# Jupyterhub not accessible using Azure Cloud

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, jupyterhub

I have two Azure cloud machines running and trying to use jupyterhub on them. One is a 'standard' ubuntu server, and one is a machine learning version where jupyterhub is already installed and running.
With both I encounter the same issue that I cannot access/use the jupyterhub. Every time I try to go to the website via a browser I get a time out.
I got the network settings set to allow incoming traffic via http, https, ssh. I tried to access it from my phone (using my LTE network not my WI-FI), yet nothing seems to give me access. All I get is a blank page...
On the 'standard machine' I instantly get a 'connection refused' error, on the 'machine learning vm' after a looooooong time I get: 'internal error - server connection terminated'

Does any one know, what could possibly be the problem here? I'm googling my way around for the last two hours but cannot find a solution....

Thanks,
Anja

Comment: There should be JupyterHub and possible other logs, right? No hints from those? Can you access one machine from the other staying within the Azure cloud?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found the problem.
I had to reinstall jupyterhub using sudo and start it using: `sudo jupyterhub --ip=0.0.0.0 --port=80`.

For some reason (perhaps documented somewhere...don't know) on an azure vm running something as 'localhost' does not seem to work and needs to done via 0.0.0.0